# Removing trailing whitespace and line returns that don't come before/after other characters

Tags: javascript, regex, whitespace

I have a text area that I'd like to adjust on a form's submit by removing line returns that don't come before or another set of characters (basically removing line removing line breaks that don't serve as paragraph breaks). Here are a few examples of the line breaks I want to remove:

**Line Returns - Before & After**

```
/* Space */
Text
/* Space */
```

**Line Return - Before**

```
/* Space */
Text
```

**Line Return - After**

```
Text
/* Space */
```

But if there was ever the case where there was in fact text that came after **ONE** line return then it would be considered okay.

```
Actual Text
/* Space */
Actual Text
```

If for argument's sake there was 5 line returns between text, 4 would be removed.

```
Actual Text
/* Space */
/* Space - Remove Me */
/* Space - Remove Me */
/* Space - Remove Me */
/* Space - Remove Me */
Actual Text
```

While exploring some solutions I thought of using `trim()` for dealing with trailing whitespace but this would presumably also remove all line returns. What would be the best way to do this?

Here is the context in which I'm replacing the text:

```
$(function() {
  $(".form").on("submit", function() {
    $("textarea").val().trim();
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you atleast try something ?

Comment: Yeah I did: `trim()`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the following regular expression will work for you:

```
text.replace(/^\s+|\s*\r?\n\s*(?=(?:\r?\n){2})|\s+$/g, '');
```

It will remove all whitespace characters (`\r`, `\n` and `\r\n`) before the actual text (`^\s+`), trailing new lines (`\s+$`) and three or more new lines in between (`\s*\r?\n\s*(?=(?:\r?\n){2})`).

```js
$('form').on('submit', function() {
  $('textarea').val(function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(/^\s+|\s*\r?\n\s*(?=(?:\r?\n){2})|\s+$/g, '');
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <textarea rows="10" cols="85"></textarea>
  <div><input type="submit"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: With the example above it removes all line breaks instead of leaving one if there are two lines of text (see my 4th example).

Comment: @CarlEdwards Ah, yeah. I have updated the answer, so now it should preserve one extra line in between.

Comment: Thanks. Would it still be possible to remove trailing whitespace in the manner of `trim()` though?

Comment: @CarlEdwards Do you want to remove spaces as well? I thought you were after new line characters only.

Comment: Yea. I apologize for the possible misunderstanding in the question's title.

Comment: @CarlEdwards Right, then we can replace `\r?\n` sequence with `\s` which stands for all whitespace characters. And that should work as `trim`.

Comment: Testing out your latest example, I created two sets of text, created a few line breaks in-between, and added trailing whitespace to both. It seems that it only removes the trailing whitespace to the second set.

Comment: No problem at all. Greatly appreciate the help if anything.

Comment: @CarlEdwards Please check now. I guess this should do the trick.

Comment: Hmm. It still seems to leave the whitespace for the first line of text I'm entering. I also inserted two line breaks in there if that helps btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
subject.replace(/(?:\s+)?(^.*?$)\s(?:\s+$)/mg, "$1\n");
```

---

```js
$('form').on('submit', function() {
  $('textarea').val(function(i, subject) {
    return subject.replace(/(?:\s+)?(^.*?$)\s(?:\s+$)/mg, "$1\n");
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <textarea rows="8" cols="50">Actual Text





Actual Text</textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Test Me">
</form>
```

---

**[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xW6mV4/3)**

---

**NOTE**
I've tested the above regex and it works with **all the examples** you've provided.

Comment: For this example as well, it removes all line breaks instead of leaving one if there are two lines of text

Comment: What do you mean by line break `\n` or `<br>` ? That's easy to modify, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yeah sorry for mixing up terminology. Basically a new line within the textarea.

Comment: FYI `\s` will match all *space* characters including spaces, tabs and newlines.

Comment: Cool. I think the only thing now is that there's still trailing whitespace if multiple spaces are added horizontally before or after the text.